# If $A\succeq{B}\succeq0$ and $C\succeq{D}\succeq0$ then $A \circ C\succeq B \circ D \succeq0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A, B,C,D \in M_n$ are Hermitian.

We define

- $A \circ B = [{a_{ij}}{b_{ij}}]$.
- $A\succeq{B}$ Iff $A-B$ positive semidefinite.

suppose $A\succeq{B}\succeq0$ and $C\succeq{D}\succeq0$.

Why does $A \circ C\succeq B \circ D \succeq0$

Comment: $A,B$ and $C,D$ are compared by completely different inequalities. How could you compare them?

Comment: There must be some typo: consider the case $n=1$ where all matrices just are scalars. Then your conditions $A\succeq B\succeq 0$ and $C\succeq D\succeq 0$ are for instance satisfied by $A=1$, $B=1$, $C=2$, $D=2$, but $A\circ B=1$ is NOT greater or equal to $C\circ D=4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just apply [Schur product theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_product_theorem) to $A\circ C=(A-B)\circ C+B\circ (C-D)+B\circ D$.